# SQL: Binary to IP Address

Tags: mysql, string, binary, string-formatting

I'm trying to convert A binary IP to a human-readable IP

```
SELECT HEX( `ip_bin` ) FROM `log_metadata`
```

gives me
    `4333D26E000000000000000000000000`

And

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(0x4333D26E)
```

gives me `67.51.210.110`

So I tried:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING( CONVERT(HEX(`ip_bin`), CHAR(32)), 1, 8 ) AS `A`
, INET_NTOA( 
  SUBSTRING( CONVERT(HEX(`ip_bin`), CHAR(32)), 1, 8 ) 
                                                     ) AS `B`
, INET_NTOA(hex(`ip_bin`))  AS `C`
, INET_NTOA(`ip_bin`)       AS `D`
FROM `log_metadata`
```

But I only get

```
+----------+------------+------------+---------+
| A        | B          | C          | D       |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+
| 4333D26E | 0.0.16.237 | 0.0.16.237 | 0.0.0.0 |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably is the missing `0x` in front of the string `A`.

Comment: Tried that. It just returned `0` and `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
mysql> select inet_ntoa(conv('4333d26e', 16, 10));
+-------------------------------------+
| inet_ntoa(conv('4333d26e', 16, 10)) |
+-------------------------------------+
| 67.51.210.110                       |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Check if it works there too =)

### Edit

The problem is that `inet_ntoa` seems to parse from *decimal* `strings` number representation, not hexadecimal ones, or from hexadecimal `integers`. Compare:

```
mysql> select inet_ntoa(0x4333d26e);
+-----------------------+
| inet_ntoa(0x4333d26e) |
+-----------------------+
| 67.51.210.110         |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select inet_ntoa('0x4333d26e');
+-------------------------+
| inet_ntoa('0x4333d26e') |
+-------------------------+
| 0.0.0.0                 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

### Edit

This is simpler and seems to work too:

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(CONV(ip_bin, 2, 10)) FROM log_metadata
```

Comment: I ended up using `INET_NTOA( CONV( SUBSTRING(HEX( ip_bin ), 1, 8), 16, 10 ))`

Comment: Try this: `SELECT INET_NTOA(CONV(ip_bin, 2, 10)) FROM log_metadata`

Comment: Didn't work. The problem is that the bits are on the left for some reason - `0x4333D26E000000000000000000000000`

Comment: You can try shifting those to the right. Mysql has shift operators.

Comment: MySQL seems to hate those, however. My best guess is it parses the value to be _integer max_

Comment: SELECT INET_NTOA(CONV(ip_bin, 2, 10)) FROM log_metadata ,  not working for me.

Comment: @Abhi post a new question with more details of your problem.

Answer (score 12):

When using Mysql 5.6.3 or later, it is easier to just use `INET6_NTOA` - it takes a binary string and returns the human readable format for it. It also supports both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and returns the format accordingly. So in your example you would use:

```
SELECT INET6_NTOA( `ip_bin` ) FROM `log_metadata`
```

And should get the human readable result.

Comment: - and the appropriate storage type is VARBINARY(16) - VAR because it's 4 for ipv4 and 16 for ipv6

Answer (score 7):

I found I had to call `HEX` to convert my binary field to a hex string first, so the following worked for me:

```
select inet_ntoa(conv(HEX(ip_bin), 16, 10)) from log_metadata
```

Answer (score 3):

FYI~ this works in newer version of mysql

```
 SELECT INET6_NTOA( `ip_bin` ) FROM `log_metadata`
```

which is the same as

```
SELECT INET_NTOA( CONV( SUBSTRING(HEX(`ip_bin` ), 1, 8), 16, 10 )) FROM log_metadata;
```