# Converting VARBINARY to integer or decimal representation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, varbinary

I have a MySQL (5.7.21) application database that contains IP (v4) addresses as `VARBINARY(16)` (I assume this length is meant to support IPv6).

I typically access this DB for maintenance purposes through phpMyAdmin.

I need to extract these IP addresses to some text format that I can handle with a script. PhpMyAdmin displays these columns in hex in query results, but exporting to file creates files that are difficult to handle in scripts or with a text editor.

I tried several variants of [`CAST`/`CONVERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) but nothing seems to work (in particular casts to `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED` yield `0`).

Is there a solution? Am I overlooking something?

#### Edit

OK, so a solution is using:

```
INET_NTOA ( CONV ( HEX (varbinary_column),16,10 ) )
```

But it the bin-to-hex-to-decimal really necessary or is there a shorter form?

Comment: The general way is to use `hex`/`conv`, but for ip addresses, there is an even nicer option, have a look at [SQL: Binary to IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15370721/6248528)

Comment: That would be the cherry on the cake but `column, inet_ntoa(column)` gives `aabbccdd , 0.0.0.0`, so the question is why columns with data are seen as zero?

Comment: You have to still use e.g. `conv` first to make it a number, `inet_ntoa` is, as you said, just the cherry. Check the second answer (or the last code in the question (the last "edit")), it should work for your case. If you do not get the expected result for your specific data, you should add some sample data.

Comment: Exactly what the doctor ordered, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so the real secret is to use `INET6_NTOA(varbinary_column)` (note the `6`) (works also with IP v4 addresses). Couldn't be easier...